# Read a table from an external Lua file and print its content

Tags: luatex

I am working on a project for creating some flashcard, and I have saved the strings I want to include in the flashcard in an external file called
`all_text.lua` and the data are stored in a linked list in the form `list = {next = list, value = {'front of the flash card', 'back of the flashcard'}}`and now I would like to create a flashcard for each element of `list`; wich is, give the command

```
\begin{flashcard}{front of the flashcard}
back of the flashcard
\end{flashcard}
```

I've tried with

```
\begin{luacode}
local l = list
while l do
    front = l.value[1]
    back = l.value[2]
    tex.sprint('\string\\begin{flashcard}{'.. front .. '}')
    tex.sprint( back .. '\string\\end{flashcard}')
end
\end{luacode}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your questions would be much easier to answer if you would provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Providing a full document would make testing answer much easier, especially since otherwise everyone has to create his own `list` for testing. Also what is the actual question? "Any suggestions" seems very unclear, are you asking for a general code review or are you asking about a specific problem? Maybe this would be better suited for StackOverflow, because it looks like a general Lua question.

Answer (score 3):

As I've written in  comment, I am not sure what the actual question is, but one problem in the provided code is the endless loop:

The loop variable `l` is never changed, so the `while` condition never changes. This causes the loop to output infinite repetitions of the first card. This can be fixed by adding `l=l.next` at the end of the loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\newenvironment{flashcard}[1]{\paragraph{Front}#1\paragraph{Back}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
  local list
  list = {next = list, value = {"Front of the last card", "Back of the last card"}}
  list = {next = list, value = {"Front of the middle card", "Back of the middle card"}}
  list = {next = list, value = {"Front of the first card", "Back of the first card"}}

  local l = list
  while l do
    local front, back = table.unpack(l.value)
    tex.sprint('\\begin{flashcard}{'.. front .. '}')
    tex.sprint( back .. '\\end{flashcard}')
    l = l.next
  end
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```